# Eclipse installation -"failed to create the java virtual machine" Mac OS Catalina

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I initially installed jdk 14 and realized that was wrong. I tried uninstalling jdk 14 and installing jdk 8u instead, but while the java in system preferences says that it is running 1.8.0 terminal says it is in 14 still.

```
java version "14" 2020-03-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14+36-1461)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14+36-1461, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The problem with creating a java virtual machine still exists when I try to install eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you could try and configure Eclipse itself to use as [described here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM) but, to summarise here, you need to add the following to `eclipse.ini`

```
; rest of ini file...
-vm
/usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
```

Of course tweak the memory requirements to your needs and read the full example linked to above.

Failing that you can also try and set JAVA_HOME. If you have installed a standard Java distribution on macOS then these commands could work:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8) # Select JDK 1.8
# OR
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11) # Select JDK 11
```